# Can I avoid this flexbox wrapper?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm not really sure if I need a wrapper to delimit the max-width of the container.

The `header` has a 100% width, and the `.wrapper` delimits to a 1000px max width.

Is there any way to avoid using the `.wrapper` div?

```css
body { margin: 0; }
header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: DarkRed;
}
.header-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
#logo, #tagline, #menu {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}
#logo {
  flex: 2;
  background-color: Crimson;
}
#tagline {
  flex: 5;
  background-color: Salmon;
}
#menu {
  flex: 3;
  background-color: IndianRed;
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .header-wrapper {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <div id="logo">Logo</div>
    <div id="tagline">Tagline</div>
    <div id="menu">Menu</div>
  </div>
</header>
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/Gekyzo/pen/VmovbB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will depend on your exact needs, there's no fast rule about your exact html structure when it comes to designing a page.

If you want a background color that extends the entire `100% width` but you want the content to have a hidden left/right barrier, you probably want a wrapper to force that barrier rule. otherwise, the red background will only be as wide as the `1000px` rule (or whatever you set your centered bounds to)

if you don't need a barrier and want the content/nav items to span the entire width, then you don't need a wrapper.

again, it's really up to you depending on the overall design of the component

Comment: Thanks, I think this answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

Set all div max-width, which is equal to 1000px

Comment: I dont want all divs to have a max-width of 1000px, I want the wrapper of this divs to have that property, but each one of them have a different width. I think my question just got answered by @abdul-ahmad

Answer (score 0):

what you did looks like your wrapper will always be 500px according to mediaqueries, so width of each elements are static.

You can modify your mediaqueries and remove the extra wrapper and the flex values.

Snippet below behave just like your codepen ... with a wrapper less :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: DarkRed;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
#logo,
#tagline,
#menu {
  padding: 5px;
}
#logo {
  background-color: Crimson;
}
#tagline {
  background-color: Salmon;
}
#menu {
  background-color: IndianRed;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  #logo {
    width: 100px;
  }
  #tagline {
    width: 250px;
  }
  #menu {
    width: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="logo">Logo</div>
  <div id="tagline">Tagline</div>
  <div id="menu">Menu</div>
</header>
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ENqPVp

Comment: Thats a pretty good solution, but I think I would have problems with lower width devices. Im happy with the current state of the design, having a .wrapper div with a max-width is not a bad solution for my project.
Thanks anyway!